# Sound playback issues in Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

It seems that Blender 2.82.7 can not use my sound sub-system, only in exclusive mode.
If browser is running, Blender cannot play sound in VSE. If I close the browser, re-run Blender (or choose same audio device in settings) sound is on.

But if I run browser again, it cannot play videos until I close Blender. Error message is:

> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': Device or resource busy

Note: I tried all audio devices in Blender. Just downloaded Blender 2.79b - it works fine.

Upd1.

Added "options snd_hda_intel index=1" to /etc/modprobe.d/default.conf

Now I see:

> ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
>   ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
>   ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
>   ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
>   ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
>   AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory

Upd2.

This is known bug of snap version.
Version downloaded from official site works.

Link to bug - https://developer.blender.org/T72920

Comment: Any errors showing up in the console? Consider to file a bug report (Help > Report as bug). -> [Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/31447)

Comment: ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': Device or resource busy

Comment: Glad you solved it. Suggest add your second update as answer for future visitors having the same issue. Cheers! How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug of snap version. Version downloaded from official site works.

Link to bug - https://developer.blender.org/T72920